# Access data of R package within its function when not loaded

Tags: r, package

So I need to use data in my R package functions. All is well if I do `library(myPkg)` and then use the function I need e.g.:

```
library(myPkg)
c_my_data(2)
[1] "A" "2"
```

But I can't use the function if I don't attach the package.

Restarting R session...

```
myPkg::c_my_data(2)
Error in myPkg::c_my_data(2) : object 'my_data' not found
```

I use [roxygen2 to generate the NAMESPACE file](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html) and it says:

> Datasets: all datasets are publicly available. They exist outside of the package namespace and must not be exported.

The NAMESPACE file:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(c_my_data)
```

The c_my_data.R file:

```r
#' Data Adder
#' @param x a number
#' @export
c_my_data<- function(x) {
  c(my_data, x)
}
```

Creating `my_data`:

```r
#called from datsets.R in project data-raw folder
my_data <- c("A")
usethis::use_data(my_data)
```

The data.R file:

```r
#' My data
#' A vector
#' @format ## `my_data`
#' A vector
#' \describe{
#'   \item{A}{Letter}
#' }
#' @source Me
"my_data"
```

**Is there any way I can add the data so that `myPkg::c_my_data(2)`  would work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calling `my_data` works only if the data has been previously loaded into the local environment once, by either:

- `library(MyPkg)`
- `MyPkg::my_data`
- `data("my_data", env = environment())`

When you did not use `library(MyPkg)` but also none of the other options in your script, `my_data` was never initially loaded.

But when you used `library(MyPkg)`, everything worked, which seems logical.

In [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047827/19487551), the solution is to use `data()` once in the beginning to access package data inside the function.

As kindly pointed out in the comments (@user2554330), the option `MyPkg::my_data` is working, not because it tells R where to find `my_data` - but because it has the side effect of loading the data into the local environment.

> The function myPkg::c_my_data() will be able to see all private variables in the package, and as soon as you call it, myPkg will be loaded (but not put on the search list).

`my_data` can be addressed inside the function without specifying the package origin. The reason it is not found is that it was not loaded, but not because location was unclear.

Comment: Ok, so you are right  in this case ´MyPkg::my_data´ works. I think I tried it in the original package with no avail :)  so the issue was in something else.

Comment: The method apparently worked, but the explanation looks wrong.  The function `myPkg::c_my_data()` will be able to see all private variables in the package, and as soon as you call it, `myPkg` will be loaded (but not put on the search list).  The OP didn't explain how `my_data` was created; the snippet from `data.R` doesn't create anything.  Knowing that is crucial to getting the explanation right.

Comment: sorry added, the ´my_data´ generation part, yes the explanation is a bit odd I aggree eg the ´my_data.R´ sugestion is just wrong

Comment: yes, I am sorry, the bit with the documentation script name is outright wrong. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I updated my question, could you please review if the answer is correct this time? I would appreciate your feedback.